# Why is my Apache not updating the pages until I restart?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Anything I upload to my Apache web server doesn't change until I restart.

This problem started occurring after I installed pagespeed, I later uninstalled it but the problem still persists. Apache worked perfectly before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by disabling "opcache" (whatever that is) and restarted Apache.